# ionic 4 - routed to the wrong path in app initialization

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a mobile app that is set so the login/registration page is the initial page and if they are already logged in then they are redirected to the home page. Pretty standard. What I don't understand is that when the application is launched they are directed to the home page and if they aren't logged in then they are redirected to the login page.

my app-routing.module looks like this:

```js
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
  import { AuthGuardService } from '../_guards/auth-guard.service';
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/login-register',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: 'login-register',
      loadChildren: () => import('../pages/login-register/login-register.module').then(m => m.LoginR  egisterPageModule),
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      loadChildren: () => import('../pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule),
    },
   // ...
  },
];
```

and my app.component.ts looks like this:

```js
    public initializeApp(): void {
      this.platform.ready().then((): void => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        this.authService.authState.subscribe((state: boolean): void => {
          if (state) {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
            this.notification.notificationInit();
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['login-register']);
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

auth service:

```js
  public readonly authState: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(0);
  public constructor() {
    this._ifLoggedIn();
  }
    private _ifLoggedIn(): void {
      this.userService.getUserInfo().then(
        (response: UserData): void => {
          this.authState.next(!!response);
        },
        (): void => this.authState.next(false),
      );
    }
```

This is an issue because when the application loads it is first going to the home.page.ts file and then redirected to the login-registration page, but, the user, using an Android device, can use the hardware back button to go to the home page. which is not desired.

thanks for any help!

#### update:

changed the ReplaySubject to a Subject and the issue prevails

```js
 public readonly authState: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Comment: Above the if condition ` if (state) {` please console.log() what are you getting in the state.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you make `authState` a BehaviorSubject instead of a ReplaySubject?

Comment: @AlokMali the state is just the user data details. It is just making sure that if there is an empty object it will be converted to a boolean with the double bang `!!` but an object with data will be true. also the data being received after console logging is `null` so this is fine. The problem is that the routing is first going to the home page first before getting routed to the login page

Comment: can't you use Subject instead of ReplaySubject? In your case there is no need of ReplaySubject right?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3924